# Trying to get all li tags inside ul using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the urls of the popular articles on Forbes. Each url is inside li tag and all the li tags are inside one ul tag. I tried everything I found online but couldn't get what I wanted. Can someone advise me what to do?

Comment: Your question is still a bit vague. Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried using the find_all function but couldn't get anything. In addition I tried using the select function but I got only the first tags on the site showing...

Comment: Please add your code as an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First, find `ul`:

```
ul = soup.find()
```

Then, get all `li`:

```
ul.findAll()
```

Comment: this ul is nested inside many divs, so I cant find it that way. However I did manage to find it through a div, but I still don't know how to get the li's inside it. (When I'm trying to do ul.find_all_next("li") it gives me the li's in the next ul and not in the current one)

Comment: you can try and go on www.forbes.com/ and look at the 'popular' tab on the right. I'm trying to get on Python the urls on this tab.